# Money - round decimal point to two decimal in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to use this expression to round money type to two decimal point.

```
=Format(Fields!ClosingBalance.Value,"#,##0.##")
```

The problem is I'm getting comma(,) in between, comma I do not want. 
Also, 100.00 is showing 100. Here I want 100.00.

Please help

Comment: it's good form to accept answers

Comment: I can't help noticing you have asked 74 questions and only have 189 rep. Something very wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a comma, don't place one in the format string:

```
=Format(Fields!ClosingBalance.Value,"#.##")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the format string to `#.0,00`. That will give you two fixed decimal digits. Your 'comma' is in the language settings. You can create your own culture though and assign it to the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 100.00 instead of 100 the correct `Format()` is

```
=Format(Fields!ClosingBalance.Value,"0.00")
```

In format strings `#` means `show character if non-zero` and `0` means `show character, zero included`